# Why is (0,0) a saddle point for $\ f(x,y) =2x^3 +(x-y)^2 -6$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why is (0,0) a saddle point for $\ f(x,y) =2x^3 +(x-y)^2 -6$?

I calculated the first partial derivatives of$\ f$  and noticed they where both$\ 0$ at$\ (0,0)$, after trying to use the second derivative test, I got that:

$\ D = f_{xx}(0,0)f_{yy}(0,0) - (f_{xy}(0,0))^2 =0$

The test is inconclusive, so I tried to think about 2 functions, one that reaches its minimum at$\ 0$ and similarly, one that reaches its maximum at$\ 0 $.

Let $\ g(y) = f(0,y)=y^2-6$ so$\ g$ reaches a minimum at $\ y=0$

But I'm struggling to find a function that reaches its maximum at$\ 0$, is there a technique to find it?

Comment: True, sorry!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $g(x)=f(-x^2,x)=  -2x^6-6 $.

Comment: $\ g(x) = f(-x^2,-x^2)=-2x^6 -6$ is actually what works here, but thanks to you I got the answer, thanks!

Comment: you're right, I didn't notice the $x$ inside of parentheses @DavidTomahak